# Sonos: Player not calling getMediaURI

Tags: sonos

Working on a Sonos API implementation for a streaming service.

I've got the getMetadata flow setup as:

1. Open Music Source: Return a list of station groups as a mediaCollection.itemType = container
2. Click Group: Return a list of stations for the selected group as mediaCollection.itemType = program
3. Click Play: Returns a single mediaMetadata with itemType = stream

I see a number of calls to getExtendedMetadata from the Windows controller on my dev machine and the player I'm trying to send the stream to.

The Now Playing shows Track and Album information, but the player does not make the getMediaURI request.

When I look at the controller log, I see the follow two errors:

```
&lt;ApplicationData&gt;@Module:asyncio @Message:Async get  failed 1. Error 0x80000002&lt;/ApplicationData&gt;
```

```
&lt;ApplicationData>@Module:asyncio @Message:RAsyncGETIOOperation  failed. Error (1000, 0x00000000)&lt;/ApplicationData&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael,
A program on Sonos is defined as a programmed radio station.  This is a case where you can return a selection of tracks on each request and they are played sequentially.  (Think Pandora, 8Tracks, Songza or similar DMCA style radio).

If you are returning a list of radio streams (even if it is only a list of one) the type for that mediaCollection should be collection, container or other.

If you do this and return the stream as a playable item and then click play on the stream you should see the appropriate calls and playback should begin.